# How to communicate with USB audio interfaces through Sandboxing?

Tags: macos, audio, usb, sandbox

I am finishing up an OS X app that needs to connect to the user's default audio output as set in the System Preferences.

Everything works fine as long as Sandboxing is not enabled.  When it is, however, things start getting iffy.

In case the user's default audio output is through a USB interface, I have `com.apple.security.device.usb` enabled.  In case their USB interface is not Sandbox-safe, I also have these enabled:

```
<key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.mach-lookup.global-name</key>
<array>
<string>com.apple.midiserver</string>
<string>com.apple.midiserver.io</string>
</array>
<key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.audio-unit-host</key>
<true/>
```

I'm still getting these two violations, however:

```
kernel: Sandbox: sandboxd: deny mach-lookup com.apple.coresymbolicationd
sandboxd: deny iokit-open AudioUserClientTascamUSBMKII
```

What's going wrong here, preventing me from communicating with the audio interface?

Furthermore, here is how I'm obtaining the correct audio component:

```
AudioComponentDescription defaultOutputDescription;
defaultOutputDescription.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Output;
defaultOutputDescription.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_DefaultOutput;
defaultOutputDescription.componentFlags = 0;
defaultOutputDescription.componentFlagsMask = 0;

AudioComponent defaultOutput = AudioComponentFindNext(NULL, &defaultOutputDescription);
OSErr error = AudioComponentInstanceNew(defaultOutput, &_componentInstance);
```

I've also tried using the flag `kAudioComponentFlag_SandboxSafe` for both the `componentFlags` properties.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed to find the problem.

It appears as though some audio drivers (in this case, by Tascam for the US-122mkII) use the OSX HAL driver, which means it plugs into the app's process.  Since sandboxed apps can't access the hardware, this is what's preventing it from working.  (Though I wonder if there is some undocumented entitlement that will allow this.)

Hopefully drivers like this can/will be updated at some point..